# Ubuntu 18.04 Hangs after screen Lock

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 Hangs once it is kept in locked screen for a while (approximately 1 hour).It can be noticed when you are working on any text editor, After every save action the system hangs for few seconds. Please help me to solve this issue.(dell Inspiron 15 3000 i5 8th gen)

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! If I understood correctly, this behavior only happens **after** a screen lock? Everything works normally even after hours of work if not locked?

Comment: Same problem here...it has been a smart decision to drop Unity, where all was working well, for a buggy and oldish project of 90' like Gnome.

Comment: @MrShunz Yes. Everything works normally even after hours of work if not locked. Every time I had to restart my system before I can resume my work after screen lock. One of my colleague is also facing this same issue.

Comment: This happens to me as well.  The crash is sometimes so severe that there are no entries whatsoever in /var/log/wtmp, output of last -x just shows computer booting up again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, which started when I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04. I discovered that if I removed the low-latency kernel I had installed a year ago, that the problem went away (so far!).